# Python Executable Upon Double Click

Tags: python

I know how to make a python script run using the terminal to open it. I would like to know how to open in the terminal upon a double click.

Answer (score 1):

Create a .desktop file with this in it:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Python Script Name
Comment=Open Python script (name)
Exec=python "/home/user/path with any spaces/to/script.py"
Icon=/usr/share/pixmaps/idle.xpm
Terminal=true
Type=Application
Categories=Application;
```

Save it in /home/user/.local/share/applications

Make it executable by right clicking, going to the permissions tab, and ticking "Allow executing as program"